# Node.js script appears to be synchronous even though I would expect it to be asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, flask

I'm doing a Node.js exercise (from [Nodeschool.io](https://nodeschool.io/#workshoppers)) which reads:

```
 # LEARN YOU THE NODE.JS FOR MUCH WIN!  

 ## JUGGLING ASYNC (Exercise 9 of 13)  

  This problem is the same as the previous problem (HTTP COLLECT) in that  
  you need to use http.get(). However, this time you will be provided with  
  three URLs as the first three command-line arguments.  

  You must collect the complete content provided to you by each of the URLs  
  and print it to the console (stdout). You don't need to print out the  
  length, just the data as a String; one line per URL. The catch is that you  
  must print them out in the same order as the URLs are provided to you as  
  command-line arguments.
```

In order to test my implementation, I made a little Flask app like so:

```
from flask import Flask
import time

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/1")
def hello1():
    time.sleep(1)
    return "Hello 1! "


@app.route("/2")
def hello2():
    time.sleep(0.5)
    return "Hello 2!"


@app.route("/3")
def hello3():
    return "Hello 3!"
```

To get me started on the Nodeschool exercise, I wrote the following Javascript code (`jugglingAsync.js`):

```
var http = require('http');
var bl = require('bl');

var handler = (response) => {
    response.pipe(bl(function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err)
    }
    console.log(data.toString())
    }))
}

http.get(process.argv[2], handler)
http.get(process.argv[3], handler)
http.get(process.argv[4], handler)
```

However, If I run this script, I see the responses 1-3 printed in that order, instead of the reverse order:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:learnyounode kurtpeek$ node jugglingAsync.js http://localhost:5000/1 http://localhost:5000/2 http://localhost:5000/3
Hello 1! 
Hello 2!
Hello 3!
```

If these commands are run asynchronously, however, I would actually expect the results to be printed in reverse order. Can someone explain why this is not the case?

Comment: I guess time.sleep() is pausing all other routes. I don't think hello2 or hello3 is answering until time.sleep is done.

Comment: I started the Flask server using `FLASK_APP=hello.py flask run` and it would appear that unlike Django, the development server doesn't immediately adapt to changes you make in the source code; after stopping and re-running it I did experience the expected wait times. (I had added the `time.sleep` statements later). So it would appear that the issue is the Javascript code after all; I've updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: I am still thinking that while time.sleep() is called, other routes are not responding. I think you can test this by having a long sleep on a route, like a minute, and inside browser trying to access another route.

Comment: I tried that, but the second view works fine within that minute. As I understand it each request runs in a separate thread?

Comment: I have just run your code on my local env and the output was:

C:\Users\me>node test.js http://localhost:5000/1 http://localhost:5000/2 http://localhost:5000/3
Hello 3!
Hello 2!
Hello 1!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out [Theodor B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2719045/theodor-b) is right: by default, the underlying Werkzeug server of Flask runs in a single thread and can only process one request at a time. In order to run it multi-threaded, one has to pass `threaded=True` to `app.run()` (cf. http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/serving/#werkzeug.serving.run_simple):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(threaded=True)
```

Now the Node.js script prints the expected output:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:learnyounode kurtpeek$ node jugglingAsync.js http://localhost:5000/1 http://localhost:5000/2 http://localhost:5000/3
Hello 3!
Hello 2!
Hello 1!
```